# Replace outliers from all columns with mean

Tags: pandas, outliers

How can i replace an outlier from a column of a pandas dataframe with the mean of the column?

I tried in this way:

```
median = dt[feature].median()
std = dt[feature].std()
outliers = (dt[feature] - median).abs() > std
dt[outliers] = np.nan
dt[feature].fillna(median, inplace=True)
```

but my 1000 x 784 dataframe become a 0 x 784 daframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should do it like this instead :

```
median = dt[feature].median()
std = dt[feature].std()
dt.loc[(dt[feature] - median).abs() > std,feature]=np.nan
dt[feature].fillna(median, inplace=True)
```

My guess it is that your problem with your old code was :

```
dt[outliers] = np.nan
```